# Flutter Braintree Plugin Safety

Tags: flutter, dart, payment, braintree, flutter-plugin

I want to use the Flutter Braintree Plugin https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_braintree for a Marketplace App. But i am recently asking myself, if this is safe to use without getting strugle with scam or something else. Can someone give me an advice or does somenone have a better alternative?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I personally look at the likes and popularity of a package before use it. For this package its version is 2.3.1. it has likes enough and they updated the package 18 days ago. That means the developers of the package still try to develop the package. That is good because if you face with an error that you didn't get. You can create an issues on github and they probably feedback you about it.